# Discord Bot RPC errors loading with Client

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am new to Discord.js.
I have been learning how to make a Bot for a day or two but I have practiced in the past with other projects.

I was able to get my Bot Online of course, but then I wanted to get into making the RPC (Rich Text Presence) and I at first tried logging the Client and the RPC.Client in as 2 different objects but it crashed the server...

This is my newer coding which I think might work if I find out what isn't working.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, RPCCloseEventCodes } = require("discord.js");
const RPC = require('discord-rpc');
const WOK = require('wokcommands');
const path = require('path');


const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const { timeStamp } = require("console");
dotenv.config();

const client = new RPC.Client({ transport: 'ipc' })

    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],



async function setActivity(){
    if (!rpc) return;
    rpc.setActivity({

        details: 'Text Based Roleplay',
        state: 'Playing Grand Theft Auto: RP',
        startTimeStamp: '1507665886',
        largeImageKey: 'rpc_icon',
        largeImageText: 'Carl Johnson',
        buttons: 
        [{
            label: 'YouTube',
            url: 'https://www.youtube.com',
        }, {
            label: 'Google',
            url: 'https://www.google.ca',

        
        }],
    })
}


console.log('RPC is Running');




client.on('ready', (c) => {
    console.log(` ${c.user.tag} is Online!`);

    setActivity();

    new WOK({
        client, 
        commandsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'commands'),
        featuresDir: path.join(__dirname, 'features'),
        testServers: '1087164983055499315',
        botOwners: '1071740521497763900',
    });

client.login(process.env.TOKEN, process.env.clientID);
```

**Error:**

> [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
> RPC is Running
> C:\Users\Pytho\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\Bot\node_modules\discord-rpc\src\client.js:111
> reject(new Error('connection closed'));
> ^

Error: connection closed
at IPCTransport. (C:\Users\Pytho\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\Bot\node_modules\discord-rpc\src\client.js:111:16)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
at IPCTransport.emit (node:events:527:28)
at C:\Users\Pytho\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\Bot\node_modules\discord-rpc\src\transports\ipc.js:141:18
at decode (C:\Users\Pytho\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\Bot\node_modules\discord-rpc\src\transports\ipc.js:92:5)
at Socket. (C:\Users\Pytho\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\Bot\node_modules\discord-rpc\src\transports\ipc.js:120:7)
at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
at emitReadable_ (node:internal/streams/readable:578:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I have tried to make it so I can login to my Bot on Discord and interact with it while it also displays my RPC for that Bot.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I knew what I was trying to do with RPC, which is, I thought it would make it so my Bot had that in his description... Just realized that this whole time it is meant for User Profiles.

I have now solved my problem, I am satisfied.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).